issue in converting rows to columns
I am converting the rows to columns in snowflake and the results are getting what I need, can some one share the inputs here.
input:

output should be:

I tried with the query like below, which is not giving the expected output.
select 
Run_ID,
table_name,
Date_val,
sum(case when type ='SRC' then count else null end) as SRC_TBL,
sum(case when type = 'TGT' then count else null end) as TGT_TBL
from table;

Please share the inputs, Thanks in advance

You need GROUP BY Run_Id, table_name, date_val.

What is the deciding factor on which "table_name" value ends up appearing in your output?  When you perform aggregations (like SUM) on some columns in your query, you will still get distinct rows for any other columns that do not have an aggregation applied.  So perhaps you want the MIN of the "table_name" column?  Otherwise, you will have to decide the aggregation to apply to that column, if there are multiple possible values (but you don't want to see a row for every possible value)

Your Input is:

and output

It's difficult how you merge both data. Because your table_name & date_val are different. 
So, it's not mention how you merge/group them.
For my understand I think you are grouping over Run_ID and taking first not null value of columns table_name & Date_value.
So, your SQL query should be:
SELECT Run_ID,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(table_name), '.*(?=\,)', 1, 1, 'i') as table_name,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(date_val), '.*\(?=\,)', 1, 1, 'i') as date_val,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type ='SRC' THEN COUNT END) as SRC_TBL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type ='TGT' THEN COUNT END) as TGT_TBL
FROM sTable
group by Run_ID;


Query: db<>diddle
